# How to install pyodbc for Python 3.5 or 3.3 on windows 7

Tags: python, python-3.5, pyodbc, python-3.3

I need to install pyodbc to use with python 3.5 or python 3.3 on Windows 7. when I use pip I get the error saying:
"could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyodbc (from versions:) No matching distribution found for pyodbc"

When I check https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyodbc/ I don't see corresponding version. 
Could someone confirm that there is no pyodbc for 3.5 or 3.3? if that's the case, how can I get connected to MS SQL Server?

Comment: "pip install pyodbc" throws that error?  Make sure your CMD box is opened as an admin.

Comment: What is the exact command you are running for pip? You should just use `pip install pyodbc`, NOT `pip install pyodbc==3.3` or anything like that. If you include a version with `pip` it is the version of what you are installing, NOT the Python version.

Comment: [This page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyodbc/4.0.17) lists Windows wheel files for Python 3.5 (cp35) but not for Python 3.3. So, `pip install pyodbc` should work with Python 3.5. (If you have both versions installed then make sure that you're running the copy of`pip` that corresponds to Python 3.5.)

Comment: Using VS Code, I just had to open a terminal prompt (as admin) and type in `pip install pyodbc` and it worked for python 3.6 x64 in Win10.

Comment: This is unrelated to the question, but when it prompts you to upgrade pip to the latest version, you can do so like this: python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Answer (score 2):

Try installing using

```
pip install pyodbc
```

in cmd as administrator.

If you are unable to install or getting cl.exe error, then you could change `import pyodbc` to `import pypyodbc` in your script.  That module is similar to pyodbc but is purely python, so it is easy to install:

```
pip install pypyodbc
```

Answer (score 1):

Steps that worked for me:

1. [pyodbc list](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyodbc/4.0.17)
   here is a list of whl files. Download the right one for you.
2. Open cmd as administrator and go to the directory containing the file.
3. Run `pip install pyodbc-xxxxx.whl`.